# Keyboard layout Dutch

Tags: keyboard-layout

Installed Lubuntu on an old laptop with Dutch keyboard layout as pictured below.

Lubuntu has no option to configure Dutch keyboard.
How to achieve a Dutch keyboard layout?

The Dutch keyboard has the @ key top left. 
See:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Nederlandse_toetsenbordindeling_-_tekst_als_paden.svg

Comment: wiki on this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard

Comment: me too my fellow dutchy :) never played with lUbuntu :D

Comment: Thanks anyhow...did find the Dutch keyboard in the Keyboard layout handler!